# VBA that will auto sort a column containing formulas in the cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column (D) that's calculating the average of the two columns next to it (B, C). I need to auto sort the result of the formula in column D in decending order when ever a change is made to B or C. Column D cells contain the formula =IFERROR(C2/B2,0)

B and C are updated via a formula that adds data from another sheet.

```
a       b   c   d
5L2R    1   0   0%  
5R2T    2   0   0%  
5P1V    1   1   100%    
611Q    1   1   100%    
5I31    1   1   100%    
5N32    1   1   100%    
642O    1   1   100%
```

I tried various different code from other similar posts but nothing is working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
Range("D1").Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to use Worksheet_Calculate() event.  Though `Target` is not a part of this event and will need to change the code slightly.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner.  Could you be a little more in depth than that?  I don't know much about writing vba code.

Answer (score 0):

Brink,

You need to provide sort a little more information and you don't want to check on column D for changes, rather check the columns it depends on for its input (B & C).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
  Dim lLastRow As Long
  
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:C")) Is Nothing Then
  
    lLastRow = [A1].End(xlDown).Row
  
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D1:D" & lLastRow), _
          SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
          Order:=xlAscending, _
          DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range("A1:D" & lLastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
  End If
    
End Sub 'Worksheet_Change
```

HTH

[image]

Comment: I'll give this a try though I found a work around by adding a sort button to the sheet and I use that when I need the data sorted.